# addclass in mootool.js

Tags: mootools

hi i am using mootool.js and i want to use two buttons (show/hide).There is li on my html page id as list.This is in loop (200 li has same id).i want to show hide images on onclick function of buttons.for this i have made a javascript in which i have send the value show and hide and write this line in javascript  `$('li#list').set('class','hide')` and made a css as  hide set display as none but this is produce a error that li#list is null tell me where i am wrong

```
<li id=list>
 <span>img tag</span>
</li>
<li id=list>
 <span>img tag</span>
</li>
```

.
.
200times

Comment: Id's cannot be duplicate. Change it to `class` attribute instead. To select multiple elements in MooTools, use the double dollar function. `$$("li.list")`, or more preferably `document.getElements('li.list')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey it appears you are using $$ and $ incorrectly. The correct use is $('idWithoutHash') and $$('.cssSelector'). $ returns a single element, $$ returns an element collection. Also you can add and remove CSS classes using the Element.addClass and Element.removeClass methods, this helps if you want to multi-class an element.